# How to make Jenkins accessible by hostname?

Tags: http, nginx, jenkins

I created an Ubuntu `19.10` VirtualBox VM and installed installed there OpenJDK `8`, Nginx `1.16.1`, and Jenkins `2.222.1`. I can access via HTTP IP address, like `http://{IP_OF_THE_VM}:8080`. Now I want also to be able to access it by the hostname like `https://jenkins.ciserver.loc/`.

Here is the VHost file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/jenkins.ciserver.loc`:

```
upstream jenkins {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.ciserver.loc;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins.error.log;

    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://jenkins;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

}
```

When I request `http://ci.ciserver.loc` in the browser, "*This site can’t be reached*" and the request end up in a `ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED`.

**How to configure Jenkins and/or Nginx correctly to make Jenkins accessible by the hostname?**

---

**SOLVED**

It was a stupid typo... I set `server_name` to `jenkins.ciserver.loc`, but was all the time trying to request `ci.ciserver.loc`. Now I corrected the requested URL to `http://jenkins.ciserver.loc` -- and it started working.

Comment: Well, this is totally unrelated to Jenkins, and partly even to nginx. This is more about DNS lookup, which you perhaps could read some basic tutorials about...

Comment: First of all, you should make sure that your server / VM can be reached from a command-line ping with `ping ci.ciserver.loc`. If that is not the case, DNS must be configured accordingly.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Thank you for you comments! Yes, it can: `ping jenkins.ciserver.loc` (executed from my host system) returns `Ping statistics for 192.168.56.103: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)`, so this part seems to be working.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Solved. It was just a typo, see the update above.